# Is an 50 ft/lb air wrench (not impact wrench) strong enough to remove brake assemblies

Tags: brakes

I can't get an impact wrench in there. Any idea if a standard 3/8" 50 ft/lb air wrench will be strong enough to remove the fasteners needing to be removed to replace the brake pads and disk ? Could spend 4 times as much and get a 100ft/lb 1/2" model ?

Comment: Depends on the torque applied to the fastener and any extra torque required to break free any corrosion since it was set. We need more information.

Comment: Also, do you mean air ratchet (since you can't fit an impact)? Those won't have any where near enough torque to loosen, but they are nice to remove already loosened bolts.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with utilizing a regular socket wrench with the correct attachments? It is my experience if you utilize power equipment to reattach such fasteners, you will over tighten and quite possibly strip out the fasteners in the process.

Will it take it off, quite possibly, depending on how much torque was applied to mount them in the first place.

Comment: I agree.  Use a breaker bar if you can, or for tighter spots, a wrench with a length of pipe on it for leverage.  Once the bolt or nut is moving, you can use the ratchet or power wrench of your choice to speed the rest of the removal.

Comment: OP specifically mentioned removal, not attachment.

Answer (score 1):

To actually answer the question, no, 50 ft lbs won't be strong enough.  Typical brake caliper (you need to remove the caliper to remove the disc) bolt torque is over a 100 ft lbs.  For example, 2003 Dodge Caravan caliper bolts are supposed to be torqued to ~125 ft-lbs.

Answer (score 0):

Specified tightening torque can very greatly from vehicle to vehicle. Anywhere from 25-100 ft. lbs. Since brake calipers tend to be exposed to the elements, you will probably need a bit more to break it free.